# asp mvc DropDownList how to pass a selected item in visual basic .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

asp mvc DropDownList how to pass a selected item in visual basic .net
i put this in the view: 
 <%=Html.DropDownList("Estados", ViewData("EstadosList"))%>
and the compiler says 
that i have to convert to SelectList becouse ViewData Returns an Object
any idea to do this?

thxs..
Fernando Soruco

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve your problem. One is faster, and one is better...

1. Better version:

   Change your view to a strongly typed one, by changing the `Inherits` attribute of the `Page` tag on the top to

   ```
   Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Web.UI.WebControls.SelectList>"
   ```

   (or whatever the full namespace "path" to the `SelectList` class is...)

   In your Controller action, you send the `SelectList` to the view as the `Model` object, by using

   ```
   Return View(theSelectListYouCreatedWithItemsFromTheDataStore)
   ```

   or, if you're returning a view with a different name than the controller action:

   ```
   Return View("theViewName", theSameSelectListAsAbove)
   ```

   In your view, you pass the `Model` object, now strongly typed to a `SelectList` because of the View's inheritance, to the helper method:

   ```
   <%= Html.SelectList("Estados", ViewData.Model) %>
   ```
2. Faster version:

   Cast the `ViewData["Estadoslist"]` object to a `SelectList` before you send it to the helper method:

   ```
   <%= Html.SelectList("Estados", CCast(ViewData["EstadosList"], SelectList)) %>
   ```

Comment: And if you already send another model to your view, you could wrap them both in a EstadosViewModelWrapper class, which take all the other things you need as properties and gets passed down as the model object instead.